# Configure Godaddy DNS with Cloud Foundry

Tags: dns, cloud-foundry

We have two web sites deployed on Cloud Foundry and want to run one web site on the root level, the other as a sub domain.

We've created a domain `domain.tld` in our Cloud Foundry org:

```
$ cf domains
Getting domains in org myorg as me...
name                            status   type
cfapps.myprovider.com           shared
domain.tld                      owned
```

In addition to that, we have created two routes:

```
$ cf routes
Getting routes for org myorg / space prod as me ...
space         host      domain               port   path   type   apps                service
prod                    domain.tld                                app1
prod          app2      domain.tld                                app2
```

Now, I need to configure the DNS.

The Cloud Foundry documentation says:

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-6/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#domains-dns

> To use your root domain (for example mydomain.com) for applications on
>   Elastic Runtime you can either use custom DNS record types like ALIAS
>   and ANAME, if your DNS provider offers them, or subdomain redirection.

In Godaddy, we can't find ALIAS or ANAME record types. Godaddy only offers us the following options. Does that mean we can't use ALIAS or ANAME? What provider does support it?

[image: Godaddy DNS record types]

Furthermore the documentation says:

> If your DNS provider does not support ANAME or ALIAS records you can
>   use subdomain redirection, also known as domain forwarding, to
>   redirect requests for your root domain to a subdomain configured as a
>   CNAME.

Does this mean we need to point the root domain to my provider and let them forward to something like `www.domain.tld`? We want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can make it work the way you would like if you want to use GoDaddy's DNS hosting.  They don't support ANAME or ALIAS records (as of me writing this).  If you want to go that route, you'll need to use another DNS provider that supports these non-standard record types.

[See this SO post for more details](https://serverfault.com/questions/486406/configuring-cname-record-in-godaddy-control-panel).

What you can do is to instruct GoDaddy to HTTP redirect the root domain to `www` and then set `www` with a CNAME record to the route assigned to your application on CF.  I'm presently doing this to host a site with a custom domain on PWS (Pivotal's hosted Cloud Foundry).  Works great, haven't had any issues.

Ex:  two routes bound to my app

1. my-app.cfapps.io
2. www.example.com

The CNAME for `www.example.com` maps to `my-app.cfapps.io`, and `*.cfapps.io` is the default domain on PWS, for which the DNS is managed by the provider.

To be thorough I will say that you can technically setup an A record for your root domain and point that to the IP address of your CF provider.  This will let you access the site with a root domain and it won't require any HTTP redirects or alternate DNS record types.

The **problem** and the reason you wouldn't want to do this is that your DNS provider may not have static IP addresses for you to target with the A record (this is the case with PWS because it runs on AWS and IPs assigned to the ELBs can and do change).  This means that your A record will only be accurate until the IP changes.  Then your site will go down and be inaccessible until you update your DNS settings.  If your provider guarantees the IPs to their load balancers won't ever change or you don't mind some occasional downtime then you could go this route.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work using Amazon Route 53 and CloudFront. Simply set new name servers in Route 53 and created an alias on the apex to point to a CloudFront resource that points to my cloud foundry domain. It'll also cache the web app, which is great.

Comment: What DNS provider do you recommend to use with Cloud Foundry that can natively handle ALIAS or ANAME records?